# Expression Trees

Tags: java, expression-trees, treenode

I'm currently writing a class that reads lines from a txt file and sorts then using Reverse Polish Notation (RPN). I've started writing the method "printExpressionTree" that will correctly format the data from the txt file.

My code so far:

```
static void printExpressionTree(TreeNode tmp) {

    if(tmp.isLeaf()) {
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
    if(tmp.isInternal()) { //using: "( <left> <operator> <right> )"
        String ret = "";

        if(tmp.hasLeft())
             ret += printExpressionTree(tmp.left) + " ";
        ret += tmp;
        if(tmp.hasRight())
             ret += " " + printExpressionTree(tmp.right);
        //What should my stopping method be?
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble determining the correct was to structure the recursion for this method.

Comment: What is your exact question? How does your `TreeNode` look? I guess your method should return a string, and the first if should do a return, not println, no? You are still missing the `return ret;` at the end of the second if. besides what about unary operators? or multiple children?